# Does mysql index size depend on number of columns?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table in mysql with create table like below:

```
CREATE TABLE `UserData` (
    `user_id` ...
    `without_key_column1` ...
    `without_key_column2` ...
    ...
    `without_key_column100` ...
    `with_key_column1` ...
    `with_key_column2` ...
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
    KEY (`with_key_column1`),
    KEY (`with_key_column2`)
);
```

Now an alternative way to to it is split it into two tables

```
CREATE TABLE `UserData1` (
    `user_id` ...
    `without_key_column1` ...
    `without_key_column2` ...
    ...
    `without_key_column100` ...
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
);

CREATE TABLE `UserData2` (
    `user_id` ...
    `with_key_column1` ...
    `with_key_column2` ...
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
    KEY (`with_key_column1`),
    KEY (`with_key_column2`)
);
```

I am wondering is there a difference in storage size of the two non-primary keys if I split the table into two or not?

I tried googling things like "mysql index number of columns" but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no significant difference in storage for the non-primary keys in the two examples you show. Certainly not enough to warrant splitting the table.

However, splitting this into two tables would take more storage space in total, because you'd have to store the clustered index (primary key) twice.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is exactly what I was looking for. Does it mean internally all those other columns are not copied when an index is created, but the index points to the corresponding primary key?

Comment: Yes, assuming we're talking about InnoDB. Each leaf node of the index has a copy of the primary key. An index search therefore has to search two indexes: the index on the attribute column to get the PK value, then the primary key to get the row. That is, if the query needs data from any other columns besides the indexed column and the primary key.